# xcode: How to add a UINavigationController to a view controller which is different main view controller?

Tags: xcode, controller, navigation

I have 3 view controllers: view1, view2, view3 with view1 is main view.
From view1 I use presentModalViewController to call view2.

From view2 I want to use a navigation controller to call view3. How can I do that?
Can I create a view2Delegate class like appDelegate with a UINavigationController? How to use connect view2 with view2Delegate to use navigation controller of view2Delegate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Present View2 as modal view controller as follows.

```
View2 *view2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:View2];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Then in View2, add the following code to push View3

```
View3 *view3 = [[View3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View3" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view3 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I try following your suggestion but view3 still can't populate.